# Crear objetos con nombres similares con un ciclo for en python

Tags: python, loops

Quiero crear 24 matrices así:

```
import numpy as np

tabla1 = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
tabla2 = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
.
.
.
tabla24 = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
```

Para no tener que escribirlo 24 veces, pensé en usar un ciclo *`for`*, pero no conozco la sintaxis adecuada.

Probé esto:

```
for i in range(1, 25):
    tabla{i} = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
```

Pero es incorrecto.

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que queres hacer se puede usando la función [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), en este ejemplo creo e inicializo 25 objetos cuyo nombre va de variable1 a variable25:

```
for i in range(1,26):
    exec('variable{} = 0'.format(i))
```

Usando tu ejemplo

```
for i in range(1,26):
    exec('tabla{} = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))'.format(i))
```

Un comentario importante: [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) es una función potencialmente peligrosa, en particular si la usamos con sentencias escritas por el usuario, debiéramos limitar su uso a casos bien controlados.

Otra forma un poco más extraña es acceder directamente al diccionario  [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) o [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), por ejemplo:

```
for i in range(1,26):
    globals()['tabla{}'.format(i)] = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
```

Comment: Perfecto! la función exec era lo que necesitaba. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

en python algo puede ser repitdo N veces si esta en una lista.

```
>>>['hola'] * 25 
# ['hola', 'hola', 'hola'....] como lo mostrado.
```

Podría serte útil en algún momento.

Ahora range crea Rangos desde 0 a n, es decir range (1,25) creara un rango de 1 a 24

Según creo lo que tu ocupas es algo como esto. Nota que tabla[i] usa "[]" y no "{}" para acceder a la lista, una matriz al final de cuenta es una lista de lista.

```
tablas = dict() # Declaramos el diccionario
for i in range(0, 25):
    tablas['tabla'+str(i+1)] = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))
tablas['tabla1'] # para mostrar lo guardado en tabla1
```

Espero eso te funcione.

Comment: oh, gracias, solo que yo no quiero crear una matriz de matrices, sino utilizar los nombres de variables tabla1, tabla2, ... tabla24 sin tener que repetir código 24 veces...

Comment: Ok, entonces si esta bien como dices
pero entonces algo como esto
tablas = dict()
for i in range(0, 25):
    tablas['tabla' + i] = np.empty((25*5,3 + 11))

Y las llamas como tablas['tabla1']

Comment: Edito el codigo para que quede más claro revisa si a si te sirve

Comment: Alejandro solo por si te interesa, puedes crear el diccionario usando  dict comprehension y el método format: `tablas = {'tabla{}'.format(n):np.empty((25*5,3 + 11)) for n in range(1,26)}`. Existe la posibilidad de crear variables al vuelo de varias formas como editar los diccionarios que definen el namespace `globals` o `locals`, usar `exec()`/`eval()` o `setattr()` si estamos usando clases. Es posible pero no recomendable, recuerda el zen de Python: Explícito es mejor que implícito. La forma que propone Alejandro suele ser la acertada para la mayoria de los casos.

Comment: Ciertamente es más "pythonico" (como nos gusta ese termino a los pythoneros) y en efecto generalmente genero así las listas, tuplas y diccionarios. Buen comentario FJSevilla.